# how to distinguish Object type from Array type in Typescript

Tags: arrays, object, typescript, types

how to check a type of an Object or of an Array?

I'm trying to add an Object (and add only if it's Object) to some Array.

```
//1. should add this OBJECT to the array
var objToAdd11 : Object = {name: 'Zack', age: 24};
this.addObject(objToAdd11);

//2. should throw errorbecause this is ARRAY, and we need only OBJECTS
var objToAdd22 : Array  = [{name: 'Zack', age: 24}];
this.addObject(objToAdd22);

public  addObject(obj: any) : void {
   /*I need to check is obj parameter OBJECT OR ARRAY*/
   var myArray : Array = [1, "a", 3];

   function () {
       myArray.push(obj);
   }

   var newMyArray : Array = myArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Array.isArray()** to check if it's an array otherwise add it

```
var objToAdd11 : Object = {name: 'Zack', age: 24};
this.addObject(objToAdd11);

//2. should throw errorbecause this is ARRAY, and we need only OBJECTS
var objToAdd22 : Array  = [{name: 'Zack', age: 24}];
this.addObject(objToAdd22);

if(!Array.isArray(objToAdd11)){
 //add to list
}
```

Please check https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray?v=example

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

You can check for object by `Object.keys(obj).length > 0 && obj.constructor === Object`. Hope it helps.

```
//1. should add this OBJECT to the array
var objToAdd11: Object = {name: 'Zack', age: 24};
this.addObject(objToAdd11);

//2. should throw errorbecause this is ARRAY, and we need only OBJECTS
var objToAdd22: Array  = [{name: 'Zack', age: 24}];
this.addObject(objToAdd22);

public  addObject(obj: any) : void {
   /*I need to check if obj parameter is OBJECT OR ARRAY*/
   var myArray: Array = [1, "a", 3];

   if(Object.keys(obj).length > 0 && obj.constructor === Object) {
      myArray.push(obj);
   } else {
      console.error("Obj is not an Object");
   }

   var newMyArray: Array = myArray;
}
```